# JScript Button working in chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have a script which basically appends attributes when a button is clicked. Script is as follows;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.generateRow = function() {
    var d = document.getElementById("add");
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.setAttribute('pattern', '^[a-zA-Z ]+$');
    input.setAttribute('name', 'items[]');
    input.setAttribute('required');
    p.appendChild(input);
    d.appendChild(p);
}
</script>
```

And in my HTML I use a normal onClick function to call back the function

```
<div id="add"></div>
<p><input type="button" value="Add" name="" onclick="generateRow()"/></p>
```

The problem I am having is in my version of Chrome I am able to add a field each time the button is clicked, but in Firefox and a updated version of Chrome the button does not respond to anything.

I am using Firefox version 31.0 and i am using Chrome version 32.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NodeElement` method `setAttribute` requires two arguments, but line `input.setAttribute('required')` has only one. You have to use `input.setAttribute('required', true);` instead.

Your whole code after update:

```
generateRow = function() {
    alert('m');
    var d = document.getElementById("add");
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.setAttribute('pattern', '^[a-zA-Z ]+$');
    input.setAttribute('name', 'items[]');
    input.setAttribute('required', true);
    p.appendChild(input);
    d.appendChild(p);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VCdwf/)

Comment: WOW, I never thought that would be it and here I was scratching my head for a couple of days. Thanks a lot it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ7T5/2/ its link to fiddle problem is in setAttribute("required"). Its asking for two params while you are only passing one

```
window.generateRow = function() {
    var d = document.getElementById("add");
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.setAttribute('pattern', '^[a-zA-Z ]+$');
    input.setAttribute('name', 'items[]');
    input.setAttribute('required', true); // THIS IS ERR
    p.appendChild(input);
    d.appendChild(p);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have 2 similar answers which are same and correct so I will have to be fair and accept the person who answered first. Thanks again.

Comment: @RuzrollerAndhar thats fine it helped and query is resolved that is all that matters friend .. :)